# laravel 5 custom config directories

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to create a modular application in laravel, 
So in my app/Modules directory, I create folder for each module.

Inside each module lies ( models, controllers, views) directories.

I want to put some config vairables for some module , So created config/config.php inside each module, but I can't make it work..

The content of the my config file is:

```
<?php
return [
    'test' => 'good',   
];
```

When I try to access this config variable from my controllers like that:
    echo config('test');
it doesn't work.

What is missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it..

I created a serviceProvider file for each module. and inside its boot 
`require __DIR__ . '/Config/config.php';`

Then it works fine.
For more about service providers, Read the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers

Everything about creating modular app is well explained in [package development](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages)